# Use Apple ID profile picture as user account profile picture

Tags: macos, apple-id

When I was setting up my Mac, it prompted me to select a profile picture from one of the defaults to use for my user account.

However, I would like to use my profile picture from my Apple ID as the profile picture for my user account on my Mac, and keep it in sync.

How can I do that, if possible? I'm already signed in to my Apple ID on my user account.

Answer (score 0):

macOS Monterey does this,

- by default for new user accounts,
- and for existing user accounts, change your profile picture in System Preferences → Users & Groups and iCloud will follow suit.

Comment: This answer does not address the OP's scenario: they want to have the macOS account photo sync with the photo from iCloud and stay in sync, not the other way round.